# Why isn't the post request sending cookies?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to send an HTTPonly cookie containing my refresh token to my server.  The cookie is shown below

```
res.cookie('refreshtoken', token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'strict',
    path: '/refresh_token',
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 216000000)   //    Token expires in 7 days
  });
```

I am making a post request to a server that is running on the same port/domain so it shouldn't need cors.  When I take a look at the sent request, there are no cookies sent.  I'm running my server on localhost which may be causing the issue, but I'm not sure.

Regardless if I use same-origin or include for the credentials, no cookie is sent.

```
const result = await (
          await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/refresh_token', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          })).json();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone reading this in the future, path refers to the absolute path.  So 'api/refresh_token' won't match with '/refresh_token'.  This allowed my cookie to be sent.